# why/how deploying multiple instances of a verticle

Tags: vert.x

While reading [a document](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/blob/master/vertx-mongo-client/src/main/asciidoc/java/index.adoc) about vert-x mongo client I came across following line:

> In most cases you will want to share a pool between different client instances.
>
> E.g. you scale your application by deploying multiple instances of your verticle and you want (...)

It is the last line that caught my attention. I didn't know I should scale my application by deploying multiple instances of the verticle. I plan to make a MongoDbVerticle class that will listen for queries on the event bus.

Questions are:

Am I really supposed to deploy this verticle several times?
How many times? Based on what criterias? Or have I misunderstood some basic concept? I'm new to vert-x, so that might well be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that vertx will route your request to one of the verticles that you have defined. Since vertx can be deployed over several machines you can i practice load balance you verticles that have long running operations(such as talking to a database or writing to file, etc.).

If I remeber correctly vertx uses [Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) to route the requests. That means that if you have two mongo-verticles; a and b, it will first select a then b then a again and so on.

To deploy a verticle you just use the command `vertx run <verticle>`.

Note: This is not as simple if you run your vertx instance as a fat-jar.

Comment: Doesn't look like the event bus is shared over the network. I can only share it over different processes on my local machine. I am btw using fat-jar. Why does that matter? I programatically deploy the verticles. Shouldn't that be equivalent?

Comment: Oh, I came across this - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/W09RnRBGb2w - seems I just have to choose the correct network interface in order to share event bus over the network. Then this is about horizontal scaling. I didn't realize vert-x was concerned with it. Thanks!